# Firebase Auth Web: Logout with page reload

Tags: node.js, firebase, vuejs2, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase with VueJS. Sign-up, sign-in works fine so far but as soon as I reload the page with F5 or load a page with writing to the browsers address bar directly then the auth session is killed, the user isn't signed-in anymore. It works fine as long as I don't reload the page, even if I click route links or get redirected to other pages, the user session keeps alive. It doesn't matter where I reload the page btw.

My login method:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.username, this.password).then(
                    (user) => {
                        if (user.emailVerified === false) {
                            firebase.auth().signOut()
                        } else {
                            // redirect to lobby page if user is verified and signed in
                            this.$router.push('/lobby')
                        }
                    },
                    function(err) {
                        console.log(err.message)
                    }
                )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call [`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged) in order to detect whether a user is logged in.

This method gets invoked in the UI thread on changes in the authentication state:

> - Right after the listener has been registered
> - When a user is signed in
> - When the current user is signed out
> - When the current user changes

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener#public-methods)

Example usage can be like this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    if (user.emailVerified === false) {
      firebase.auth().signOut()
    } else {
      this.$router.push('/lobby')
    }
  } else {
    // will get to here from a logout event
    // this.$router.push('/login')
  }
}
```

Comment: I put a flag in localStorage to avoid the UI fresh before firebase auth status loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your main.js file:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
if (!app) {
    app = createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
}})
```

Firebase will run before Vue app is created.